# Crystal Reports: Not pulling any results when it should

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

In this report I have created, it should be a pulling a limited amount of results.  Here are some screenshots as well as the SQL that is pulling.  The desired results will also be below:

The Design form:
[image: The Design form]

Results:
[image: Results]

Expected Results:
[image: Expected results]

Connections:
[image: Connections]

Without Param:
[image]

The Query:

```
    www.salesforce.com
 SELECT Contact_Date_of_Death__c, Type, Centers_Case_Number__c, Id
 FROM   Case
 WHERE  Type='Standard'
 EXTERNAL JOIN Case.Centers_Case_Number__c={?P:\Crystal Reports\NAV\NAVCrystal.dsn: Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job.No_} AND Case.Id={?www.salesforce.com: Opportunity.SF_Case_Id_Import__c}


P:\Crystal Reports\NAV\NAVCrystal.dsn
 SELECT "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"."Description", "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"."No_", "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"."Trust Type"
 FROM   "BFGLLC"."dbo"."Center Trust Bill Pay$Job" "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"
 WHERE  "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"."No_"={?www.salesforce.com: Case.Centers_Case_Number__c}
 ORDER BY "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job"."No_"
 EXTERNAL JOIN Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job.No_={?P:\Crystal Reports\NAV\NAVCrystal.dsn: Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry.Job No_}


P:\Crystal Reports\NAV\NAVCrystal.dsn
 SELECT "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_G_L_Account"."No_", "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry"."Posting Date", "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry"."Line Amount (LCY)", "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry"."Job No_"
 FROM   "BFGLLC"."dbo"."Center Trust Bill Pay$Job Ledger Entry" "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry" INNER JOIN "BFGLLC"."dbo"."Center Trust Bill Pay$G_L Account" "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_G_L_Account" ON "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry"."No_"="Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_G_L_Account"."No_"
 WHERE  "Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job_Ledger_Entry"."Job No_"={?P:\Crystal Reports\NAV\NAVCrystal.dsn: Center_Trust_Bill_Pay_Job.No_}


www.salesforce.com
 SELECT Commissioned_Sales_Rep__c, Biling_Notes__c, SF_Case_Id_Import__c
 FROM   Opportunity
 EXTERNAL JOIN Opportunity.SF_Case_Id_Import__c={?www.salesforce.com: Case.Id}
```

Comment: do you have any suppress condition on your details?

Comment: Only to suppress if 0 and if duplicates.

Comment: did you try same query firing on database? did the query pulled all results?

Comment: Yes, it did.  That is where I pulled the desired results from.

Comment: Does anything display if you throw a count or sum field onto your report footer?

Comment: do you get any records if the group is removed?

Comment: I get ALL of the records, which is far too many, defeats the purpose of the report, and also makes it run for like 40 minutes.

Comment: Attached a screenshot of the removed parameter.

Comment: if you removed the parameter and got records, that means the parameter is the problem, so check parameter type, capital letters, length, etc etc

Comment: I have been, that is the reason I came to here, to see if there was any information I could give to help me out with this.